# Validate User Access ADO.NET - SQL 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, ado.net

I have a simple web application and I want validate user from a simple form with Login and Password. The Codebehind of "Log in" button has the next code:

```
    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        int userId = 0;
        string CONNECTION_DEFAULT = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONNECTION_DEFAULT"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_DEFAULT))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("STP_VALIDA_USUARIO"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usu_login", txtUsuario);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usu_senha", txtSenha);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                userId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I get the following exception when I execute it:

```
No mapping exists from the type of object System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText for a managed provider native type.
```

The connection with DataBase and the Stored Procedure are working perfectly, but I can't fix this error to know if the application working right when I need validate the user. Can anyone help me understand why I am getting this exception?

Comment: Please translate your title to english.

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply `txtUsuario.Text` and `txtSenha.Text` as your parameter values, not the actual controls themselves. You are currently passing `txtUsuario` and `txtSenha` instead of their text.

Comment: thanks about "the light". What I Did?

On Front-End Page I was using "input" and then, I change to "<asp:Literal>"

Thanks again!